# Javascript UTC time not working

Tags: javascript, html, utc

So I have this code that should show different image depend on UTC time but it does not show anything, for exemple when it is Monday 00:00 it should show one image, when it is Tuesday 19:00 it should another picture do you know what is wrong here?
Thank You

This is just small part from code, because full code is to long:

```
<strong class="GeneratedText">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<p>");
    var d = moment().tz('Europe/Oslo').format('dddd');
    var hr = moment().tz('Europe/Oslo').format('k') ;

if (d=="Monday" && hr==0) {
document.write("<img src='https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e2aefa_adea8af0771845aa9e2f7e8c1c65a654~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_511,h_170,al_c,q_80/e2aefa_adea8af0771845aa9e2f7e8c1c65a654~mv2.jpg'>");
}
if (d=="Tuesday" && hr==19) {
document.write("<img src='https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e2aefa_adea8af0771845aa9e2f7e8c1c65a654~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_511,h_170,al_c,q_80/e2aefa_adea8af0771845aa9e2f7e8c1c65a654~mv2.jpg'>");
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `...tz is not a function`, probably because the timeZone addon is missing, instead you're loading Moment twice

Comment: @Beginner, only include the *moment.js* `script` once btw

Comment: `but it not working` <= Then you should describe what **does** happen in your question. Ie. **Include the expected results and the actual results**. Be detailed in your description. IE: `When today is xx date then ..... but instead I see .....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed both script tags are loading moment.js where as moment-timezone-with-data.js is also required to use tz().

I tried following code with latest moment library and I am getting correct result

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js">
</script>
  <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<p>");
    var d = moment().tz('Europe/Oslo').format('dddd');
    var hr = moment().tz('Europe/Oslo').format('k') ;

  document.write(d + '<br>');
  document.write(hr + '<br>');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For utc (no need of moment-timezone-with-data),

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<p>");
    var d = moment().utc().format('dddd');
    var hr = moment().utc().format('k') ;

  document.write(d + '<br>');
  document.write(hr + '<br>');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm just getting this: https://jsfiddle.net/51432wxc/   I don't know, maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Remove html head and body tags it should be fine https://jsfiddle.net/51432wxc/1/

Comment: But still it uses users date but not UTC

Comment: Me too, but when I changed date on my computer image also changed, which means that it is still uses image based on computers date and not UTC

Comment: Because you have specified time zone as Europe/Oslo. Updated to use UTC https://jsfiddle.net/51432wxc/2/ you can check.

Comment: Also, time will used from you local system. If you want to use server time then you have to fetch time from server.